# Featured Image automatically getting deleted when I publish the post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have a news website [www.trendingmaharashtranews.com](http://www.trendingmaharashtranews.com)

I recently migrated the website from a different host to hosting. Now when I try to publish any news and select a featured image, it is automatically getting deleted. I have also tried using a plugin for featured images, but it is not getting added.

I tried using plugin. Have disabled CDN, talked with hostinger customer services, but problem persists. There are no active plugin also.

Comment: Please read ["Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) as well as [ask] and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your post saving method.
I have gone through your website and found that the "class="post-thumb"" have no image tag and so its not rendering the image.
You can post the code that save the post for more detail on this.
i have faced the similar issue on one of my site and i know the actual problem for the issue but need your code to assist you better.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Since you are trying to understand the problem, its better add it as a comment rather than posting it as an answer.